# How to Set image Tiles like Gallery for an app for windows phone?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I need to show the Contact images on tiles randomly like a gallery, as similar to "People" tile in a windows mobile. . . Can anyone Suggest me how to do that. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called Mosaic Tile. If u need this u should use [Telerik Controls](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/radhubtile-features-mosaictile.html)

Answer (score 1):

Before you go an license Telerik controls, have a look at ImageTile control in Coding4Fun toolkit.

It does exactly that.

http://coding4fun.codeplex.com or get it from nuget

Answer (score 0):

To create an Image dynamically look into `WritableBitmap` Image for a start.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sir! But i need to create like thumbnail image [link](http://betanews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/thingy1.jpg) like this sir. . . Please Give me some Brief Info Sir. . I'm a Beginner in this type of work. . . Thanks in Advance

Comment: I guess this is similar to what you require. Hope it helps http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/